# Hosting in IIS (503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I am trying to host my WCF service in IIS 7.5, but everytime i run the website i get a page stating

Service Unavailable

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I noticed that whenever I started the website the ASP.net v4.0 stopped automatically. I checked the eventviewer and this seems to be the error

> The worker process for application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' encountered an error 'Configuration file is not well-formed XML
>   ' trying to read configuration data from file '\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.

I tried searching for solutions around the internet but none of them have been helpful so far.

1. I tried changing the identity of ASP.net v4.0 in IIS to LocalSystem and it didn't work
2. After that i tried setting up a "Custom account" by setting the username as my computer username and adding passwords but i got "The specified password is invalid, type a new password" even though i don't have any passwords for my account

3.The final thing i tried was to add IIS_IUSRS and IUSR to the security of the Web.config but still it didn't work

This is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior"
               name="HelloService1.HelloService1">
        <endpoint address="HelloService1" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="HelloService1.IHelloService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: "I tried searching for solutions around the internet but none of them have been helpful so far." - it would be useful to know what you've tried so people don't suggest it again to you.

Comment: Looks like you got an error in your web.config file. Can't really help you without the content.

Comment: @sr28 i edited the post to include whatever I've tried so far.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I posted the content in my web.config file

Comment: @NimazSheik Try removing and replacing all the "white spaces" I find often the case of such things is unprintable (non-ASCII) characters that were copy pasted from somewhere else.

Comment: Wait....WHAT THE HECK you should NEVER play around with your `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config`

Comment: @Aron i removed all the white spaces, and i did not do anything to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config i just opened it through the eventviewer and i couldn't understand it so i closed it without changing anything

Answer (score 0):

Try a re-install of the .NET Framework 4.0. Go to this location

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Run this command

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```